# Sheaves valued in a $k$-category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a $k$-category which we regard as an $\infty$-category whose objects all happens to be $k$-truncated.
A sheaf $F$ valued in $\mathcal{C}$, in the $\infty$-categorical sense, is a presheaf satisfies the gluing condition,
$$F(U) = \lim \left( \prod_{i \in I} F(U_i) \rightrightarrows \prod_{i, j \in I} F(U_i \cap U_j)
 \mathrel{\substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow \\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow}}
\prod_{i, j, k \in I} F(U_{i} \cap U_j  \cap U_k)
 \mathrel{\substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow \\[-0.6ex]
                       \textstyle\rightarrow \\[-0.6ex]
                      \textstyle\rightarrow}}
 \cdots \right)
$$
where $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of $U$ and the diagram in the limit is the standard Čech nerve of infinite length.
Since $\mathcal{C}$ is a $k$-category, a reasonable guess is that one should be able to truncate at the $k$-intersections and compute a limit over a much smaller diagram while getting the same result.
For example, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a $1$-category, then the gluing condition for a sheaf should be just $F(U) = \lim \left( \prod_{i \in I} F(U_i) \rightrightarrows \prod_{i, j \in I} F(U_i \cap U_j) \right)$ so we can recover the ordinary description.

My question is if this is true? If so, is there a way to write a clean proof or if there is a reference in the literature? (I couldn't find such a statement in Higher Topos theory.)

Ultimately, I care about the following case when $k = 2$ (for a Grothendieck topology): Quasicoherent sheaves $\operatorname{QCoh}$ defined in, for example, Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum's DAG, is a sheaf valued in the (very large) $\infty$-category of $k$-linear stable $\infty$-categories, for some field $k$ of characteristic $0$. For each scheme $X$, $\operatorname{QCoh}(X)$ has a standard $t$-structure and one should conclude that taking hearts $\operatorname{QCoh}^\heartsuit$ produce a sheaf of abelian categories or, in more classical terms, a stack without knowing the exact description of $\operatorname{QCoh}^\heartsuit(X)$.

This last statement should follows from my earlier question and I will be satisfied with a proof or reference for this $k=2$ case.
I only asked the general question since I don't see any concept difficulty to generalize the statement to $k$.
However, I wouldn't be surprised if it's hard to write an actual proof for the general case.

Comment: It is true. In a sense this is implicit in the old definition of stack explicitly in terms of descent data. I don't recall seeing a proof, though...

Comment: I guess conceptually I can see how the proof goes, e.g., when $k=1$ a direct computation will show triple intersection or more gives no restriction since any $2$-morphisms between two $1$-morphisms are identified up to arbitrary connectivity. I can imagine a similar situation for $k=2$ but it looks pretty mess above $3$ without some smart way to organize the data.

Comment: A separate note is that I wasn't asking for the classical stack description but the truncation of the Čech nerve.  It's the same thing but I think it still takes one paragraph or two (or maybe more) to check them.